# Word for beading of old cloth

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I am having trouble finding a word similar to threadbare or worn out that represents a worn garment that has started to form a bead-like texture from extensive usage. Any ideas if such a word exists?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The process is called "pilling".  The small balls of fabric are "pills".

[Pill](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pilling) (intransitive verb)

> to become rough with or mat into little balls 'brushed woolens often pill'